# Putting border-radius to the shape/image

Tags: html, css, border, pseudo-class

I want to achieve this. I dont know what to do since border-radius like cannot achieve this. the curve at the top is an image and the curve below is just a solid color. As you can see, both edges are still sharp. it can have a :before or :after but i dont know how to do it in shape.

[image]

Comment: where you uploaded the img to refer?

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/5lvvti3bv/Selection_002.jpg  i just edited it just now

Comment: share your code in fiddle or in codepen that might help.

Comment: What happens, what did you expect to happen, what have you tried?

Comment: Pls see the codepen **http://codepen.io/levine/pen/pELVda**

Comment: @AllDani it should be the exact look of the picture this is the codepen http://codepen.io/levine/pen/pELVda. the top part is an image (the blue color)

Comment: @G.L.P its above i edited it

Comment: Codepen looks great. Just add a margin.

Comment: @AllDani no it doesnt look exactly like the image

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a postion for every box, and so change the margon for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding transformation and wrapper blocks like this:

```
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 990px;
}

.box1 {
  width:990px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url('https://s9.postimg.org/vq8kj53an/Selection_025.png');
  border-radius: 0 0 40% 40%;
  transform: scalex(1.3);
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>

<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xbmbgLcc/